# a couple of questions on xy-pic

Tags: xy-pic

I used [xy-pic](http://www.tug.org/applications/Xy-pic/) to typeset the following (long exact sequence)

```
\[ \xymatrix@1{ \cdots \ \ar[r] & \widetilde{H}_n(A) \ar[r]^{i_*} & \widetilde{H}_n(X)  \ar[r]^{j_*} & \widetilde{H}_n(X/A) \ar[r]^{\partial} & \widetilde{H}_{n-1}(A) \ar[r] & \ \cdots \ \ar[r] &  \widetilde{H}_0(X/A) \ar[r] & 0  } \]
```

I was wondering if there is a (simple) way of equating each entry with something below it, in other words I would like a (short) vertical equals sign below each entry and something below that. I looked at the [guide](ftp://ctan.unsw.edu.au/tex-archive/macros/generic/diagrams/xypic/xy/doc/xyguide.pdf) but I can't find where it explains how to do this.

Also, one more thing: is there a way to control the arrow length? I couldn't find this either...

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Treat it as a "real" matrix:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}
\begin{document}

\[
\xymatrix@R=10pt@C-6pt{
  \cdots \ar[r] &
  \widetilde{H}_n(A) \ar[r]^{i_*} \ar@{=}[d] &
  \widetilde{H}_n(X)  \ar[r]^-{j_*} &
  \widetilde{H}_n(X/A) \ar[r]^-{\partial} \ar@{=}[d] &
  \widetilde{H}_{n-1}(A) \ar[r] &
  \cdots \ar[r] &
  \widetilde{H}_0(X/A) \ar[r] &
  0 \\
  & B & & C
}
\]

\end{document}
```

Notice the `R=10pt` to set the interrow spacing and `C-6pt` to reduce the intercolumn space. The labels over the arrows near the "big" objects are best announced with `^-{label}` so that they'll be placed in the middle of the visible arrow, rather than midway from the cells' centers.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for! I hadn't thought of adjusting the interrow and intercolumn spacing.